# How to add two fields in a form and show in 3rd field using Redux Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am using Redux-Form, where I have 2 fields 'client income' and 'partner income', and I need to show the sum of the values in another field, *onChange* of above 2 fields.

I tried storing the sum in a global variable but it's not working.

The behavior is like below, if I try adding 12+ 13 instead of 25, it's coming as 27. I identified the cause, it's happening as it is taking it as 1+12+1+13. I am not sure how to mitigate the issue.

I could have used *onBlur*, but *onChange* is the requirement.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example to help people answer your question. There seems to be a bug in your code that includes intermediate inputs, but without the full code, it is hard to answer. See this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `formValueSelector` to connect() to form values and these values will be available in props of your form.

```
const selector = formValueSelector('simple');

SimpleForm = connect(
  state => {
    return {
      number1: selector(state, 'number1'),
      number2: selector(state, 'number2'),
    }
  }
)(SimpleForm);
```

> [Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/62796k29ow)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use debounce? There's an NPM module [react-debounce-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-debounce-input) to give you a general idea of implementation.